# What happend when I create a Stream in Dart but not close it

Tags: flutter, dart, stream

When I create a `Stream` object in Flutter (Dart), I got a warning message that I should close this `Stream` after used it. I wonder that have any problem when I create a new `Stream` but not close it. (Seem like memory leak)

I used memory tool for finding memory leak in that's case but fail. Why should I close the `Stream`. May I miss anything about stream in Dart?

P/s: In my application, I have to create many `Stream` object and share it with many widget. It's easy to code if I don't need to manage the `Stream` instance.

Comment: I think Stream will automatically close when the widget permanently removed from the widget tree. Just close Stream when dispose is enough. It's mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55662255/flutter-streambuilder-closing-of-streams

Comment: I wonder how about detach the subscribed widget from widget tree and move the stream into another one.